# Possible to have a dynamic site base URL from entry field data?

Tags: entries, siteurl

Is it possible to have a dynamic site base URL coming from an entry's field data?

I want to do something like https://{entry->subdomainField}.example.com/{entry->slug} with entries coming from the same site.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to handle both DNS, server routing and Craft routing:

### DNS

Make sure to have a wildcard A-record for `*.example.com` so all subdomains go to your server.

### Server routing

Configure your web server (Nginx, Apache, or whatever you're using) to route all requests to `*.example.com` to the same Craft installation.

### Craft routing

You're gonna need to use [advanced routing](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/routing.html#advanced-routing-with-url-rules) to specify a routing rule that includes the domain. Check out the documentation on [routing rules with server names](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#rules-with-server-names).

Based on the example in the documentation, you could use something like this:

```
return [
    '//<subdomain:\w+>.example.com/<slug:\w+>' => 'path/to/template',
];
```

Given this documentation, your template would have access to a `subdomain` and a `slug` variable which you can use to find the correct entry based on your `subdomainField` and the entries' `slug`. If it doesn't exist, make sure to [exit with a 404 error](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/tags.html#exit).

To make this logic simpler, I'd probably point the URL route to a [module controller](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/controllers.html) instead and perform the query and validation in there. The controller can either respond with a 404 error or render the appropriate template based on the slug parameter.

---

On a broader note: Make sure that you aren't just doing extra work to get a [multi-site functionality which Craft already provides](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/sites.html) out of the box!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should have been more clear. We use Craft headless, so my concern is more in the area of the $entry->url field and the URLs that are returned by the GraphQL API. Also with the URLs that are generated to be embedded in rich text field for interlinking. And with the internal entry logic that ensures that duplicate URLs are not allowed.

Comment: We currently use https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#entry-uri-formats but that does not seem to allow for dynamic host names?

Comment: @JoshuaCoady Yes, the URI can only include the path as far as I know, not the domain and/or site prefixes. If you have a multi-site with one defined site for each possible subdomain, you can just specify the site in the `siteUrl` function and it will append the subdomain. Otherwise, maybe just use the entries' `uri` instead of `getUrl()` and construct the correct domain based on the field? Or move the domain mapping logic entirely to the frontend?